# SQL Insert Issue with parenthesis

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to insert the following string in `varchar`

```
'EXEC tasks.dbo.sp_run_job '(New) Cube Process FirstLast Dimensions New', @TaskID, @LoadID'
```

Now inserting parenthesis is the issue - is there a way to do this?

This is the complete update script I am trying to execute:

```
begin tran
   update tasks..tasks 
   set Task_SQL = 'EXEC tasks.dbo.sp_run_job '(New) Cube Process FirstLast Dimensions New',@TaskID,@LoadID' 
   where TaskID in (621)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the parentheses: the problem is the single quote immediately preceding the parentheses. Just do this to self-escape those quotes:

```
begin tran
update tasks..tasks set Task_SQL = 'EXEC tasks.dbo.sp_run_job ''(New) Cube Process FirstLast Dimensions New'',@TaskID,@LoadID' where TaskID in (621)
```

Note that I escaped both the opening quote near the parentheses and the closing quote near the comma. Sql Server will treat the two adjacent quotes as one single quote in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter binding if this is in a coding. Or use two single quotation marks insteard of one. like 
'EXEC tasks.dbo.sp_run_job ''(New) Cube Process FirstLast Dimensions New'',@TaskID,@LoadID'

Comment: Thanks.. Works now :D